# How can I get a better result when using this array function?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

`NameError: name 'np' is not defined`  This is the error i get, can someone please tel me what am doing wrong?

I'm trying to run an array function to multiply figures with this code

```
a=np.array([12, 10, 13.1])
b=np.array([11.12, 19.01, 23.11])

c=a-b
print(c)

d=a*b
print(d)
```

instead i get this error code

```
NameError: name 'np' is not defined
```

Comment: Have you read the error? What's unclear about it? You need to define `np` if you want to use it, probably by importing numpy...

Answer (score 0):

You might not have imported numpy.

Add a line at the start of your code: `import numpy as np`. Generally most people do it like this, shortening numpy to np using the `as` statement.

If you have added that line at the start of your code, then you haven't installed numpy.

Numpy isn't a built-in module or library that Python has by default, unlike modules such as `math` or `time`. It's something that you must install manually. You can do it by going to Command Prompt or Terminal and using `pip install numpy` or `pip3 install numpy`. You can also use a package manager.

For more details, see https://numpy.org/install/.